# This code can run to send email & sms notification to customer. Need to make some changes, to ensure no emails sent if email in the object is null

Tags: java

I'm stuck to make some changes on this coding, to ensure no emails sent via `bpaNotificationService` if email in `orderContacts` object (in the CustomerOrder class) is null, so it doesn't throw error logs? And also to include an info logger to say that "not sending email because no email is given".

This is only if it's email notification only, which is checking whether email notification key is not null.

Generally in the `OrderContact` list, we have `contactType` `Order`. Thus, my idea is to:

1. Use the `ContactUtil` to get the specific `OrderContact` object from `customerOrder.getOrderContact()`.
2. Once I got the specific `OrderContact` object, check whether got email to send the notifications.

```
@EEAction(value = "customer.sendNotification")
public class SendNotificationAction extends EEWorkflowAction {
    private final NotificationService novusNotificationService;
    private final sg.com.bpa.executionengine.notification.service.NotificationService bpaNotificationService;
    public SendNotificationAction(NotificationService novusNotificationService, sg.com.bpa.executionengine.notification.service.NotificationService bpaNotificationService) {
        this.novusNotificationService = novusNotificationService;
        this.bpaNotificationService = bpaNotificationService;
    }
    @Override
    public EEActionResponse executeEEAction(EEActionRequest actionRequest, CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
        log.info("Sending Notification for {} with notification type: {}",
                OrderAttributeKey.BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID.getValue(customerOrder), actionRequest.getProcessVariable(ProcessVariable.NOTIFICATION_TYPE));
        if (MailTemplate.doesNotificationExist(actionRequest.getProcessVariable(ProcessVariable.NOTIFICATION_TYPE)) ||
                SmsTemplate.doesNotificationExist(actionRequest.getProcessVariable(ProcessVariable.NOTIFICATION_TYPE))) {
            bpaNotificationService.sendNotification(actionRequest, customerOrder);
        } else {
            novusNotificationService.sendNotification(actionRequest, customerOrder);
        }
        return createResponse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is a field named `email` inside `CustomerOrder` class.

1. First `null` checking for `customerOrder` object.
2. Then `null` checking for `customerOrder.getEmail`.
3. Assume `getEmail` returns `String`, so checking if the string is empty or not.

```
@Override
public EEActionResponse executeEEAction(EEActionRequest actionRequest, CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
    log.info("Sending Notification for {} with notification type: {}",
            OrderAttributeKey.BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID.getValue(customerOrder), actionRequest.getProcessVariable(ProcessVariable.NOTIFICATION_TYPE));
    //checking email address fild null or not null.
    if( customerOrder != null && customerOrder.getEmail() != null && !customerOrder.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
        if (MailTemplate.doesNotificationExist(actionRequest.getProcessVariable(ProcessVariable.NOTIFICATION_TYPE)) ||
                SmsTemplate.doesNotificationExist(actionRequest.getProcessVariable(ProcessVariable.NOTIFICATION_TYPE))) {
            
            bpaNotificationService.sendNotification(actionRequest, customerOrder);
        } else {
            novusNotificationService.sendNotification(actionRequest, customerOrder);
        }
    }else {
        log.info("Not sending email because no email is given");
    }
    
    return createResponse();
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(customerOrder.getOrderContact())` instead? Assuming the `OrderContact` class got email. I have updated my question for your reference.

Comment: `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` returns true if the supplied `Collection` is null or empty. But in this case, Both `CustomerOrder` and `customerOrder.getOrderContact()` are not  Collection` type. So, in this place CollectionUtils.isEmpty will not give you expected result.

Comment: Is this answer helpful?

Comment: If you find this helpful, then accept and upvote it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers